# What structure can be made to avoid having to use RefCell?

Tags: recursion, rust, borrow-checker, refcell

I created some code in Rust that should allow me to set recursive Ports, Port having a source, that could have a source, etc. However, due to borrow issues the only way for me to implement this structure is through RefCell, and i actually do not want to use RefCell (it allows me to compile code that will potentially panic at runtime) or any other libraries from std.

The trouble is that it seems that i am unable to set a value to my Port due to borrow issues.

```rust
struct Port<'a> {
    value: i32,
    source: Option<&'a Port<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Port<'a> {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Port<'a> {
        Port { value, source: None }
    }

    fn link(&mut self, source: &'a Port<'a>) {
        self.source = Some(source);
    }

    fn get_source_value(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        match self.source {
            Some(port) => {
                let inner_source_value = port.get_source_value();
                match inner_source_value {
                    Some(value) => Some(value),
                    None => Some(port.value),
                }
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut top_port = Port::new(10);
    let mut sub_port = Port::new(20);
    let mut sub_sub_port = Port::new(30);

    sub_port.link(&top_port);
    sub_sub_port.link(&sub_port);

    top_port.value = 400; // can't do this because top_port is borrowed

    println!("Value of sub_sub_port's source's source's source: {:?}", sub_sub_port.get_source_value());
}
```

The trouble occurs because top_port is borrowed when sub_port and sub_sub_port are linked to it.
The fact that this happens is no surprise to me and i could use RefCell and RC to go around this issue.

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Port<'a> {
    value: i32,
    source: Option<&'a RefCell<Port<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Port<'a> {
    fn new(value: i32) -> RefCell<Port<'a>> {
        RefCell::new(Port { value, source: None })
    }

    fn link(&mut self, source: &'a RefCell<Port<'a>>) {
        self.source = Some(source);
    }

    fn get_source_value(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        match self.source {
            Some(port_ref) => {
                let port = port_ref.borrow();
                let inner_source_value = port.get_source_value();
                match inner_source_value {
                    Some(value) => Some(value),
                    None => Some(port.value),
                }
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let top_port = Port::new(10);
    let sub_port = Port::new(20);
    let sub_sub_port = Port::new(30);

    sub_sub_port.borrow_mut().link(&sub_port);
    sub_port.borrow_mut().link(&top_port);

    top_port.borrow_mut().value = 400;

    println!("Value of sub_sub_port's source's source's source: {:?}", sub_sub_port.borrow().get_source_value());
}
```

However, my goal is to not use any standard library functionality and to only use Rust in a safe way. In what way could i restructure my code to avoid having to use RefCell or any other std libraries? Or even better, could i use more lifetimes to fix my original code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "my goal is to not use any standard library functionality and to only use Rust in a safe way".  Are you implying `RefCell` is not safe?

Comment: [`RefCell` is part of `core`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/cell/struct.RefCell.html) so is available even in non-std environments.

Comment: (same as `Option`, which you are using)

Comment: "The more common inherited mutability, where one must have unique access to mutate a value, is one of the key language elements that enables Rust to reason strongly about pointer aliasing, statically preventing crash bugs. Because of that, inherited mutability is preferred, and interior mutability is something of a last resort."[1]

I am not directly implying RefCell is not safe at all, but i do want code where it is known that there are no borrow issues at compile time.

[1][link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html#when-to-choose-interior-mutability)

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for noticing that RefCell is part of Core, much appreciated!

Comment: You can use [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) for primitives as a non-panicking `RefCell`.

Comment: The lifetime on port looks like a ref flag tbh. Would something like this perhaps work for you: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e1950153edece7bb0c76618bf51877f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `core::cell::Cell<i32>` will enable the replacement of the integer without requiring `&mut` access.
Reading the integer with `.get()` is possible because `i32` is `Copy` (the `Cell` still has its content after reading it).

```rust
use core::cell::Cell;

struct Port<'a> {
    value: Cell<i32>,
    source: Option<&'a Port<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Port<'a> {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Port<'a> {
        Port {
            value: Cell::new(value),
            source: None,
        }
    }

    fn link(
        &mut self,
        source: &'a Port<'a>,
    ) {
        self.source = Some(source);
    }

    fn get_source_value(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        match self.source {
            Some(port) => {
                let inner_source_value = port.get_source_value();
                match inner_source_value {
                    Some(value) => Some(value),
                    None => Some(port.value.get()),
                }
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let top_port = Port::new(10);
    let mut sub_port = Port::new(20);
    let mut sub_sub_port = Port::new(30);

    sub_port.link(&top_port);
    sub_sub_port.link(&sub_port);

    top_port.value.set(400);

    println!(
        "Value of sub_sub_port's source's source's source: {:?}",
        sub_sub_port.get_source_value()
    );
}
```

If the code has to be used in a parallel context, then we can replace the `Cell<i32>` with an `AtomicI32`.
Its `.store()` function does not either need `&mut`.
This is due to the fact that an *atomic* is fundamentally shared (otherwise the atomicity would not be required) while still allowing mutations (it's still *interior mutability* actually).

```rust
use core::sync::atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering};

struct Port<'a> {
    value: AtomicI32,
    source: Option<&'a Port<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Port<'a> {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Port<'a> {
        Port {
            value: AtomicI32::new(value),
            source: None,
        }
    }

    fn link(
        &mut self,
        source: &'a Port<'a>,
    ) {
        self.source = Some(source);
    }

    fn get_source_value(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        match self.source {
            Some(port) => {
                let inner_source_value = port.get_source_value();
                match inner_source_value {
                    Some(value) => Some(value),
                    None => Some(port.value.load(Ordering::Relaxed)),
                }
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let top_port = Port::new(10);
    let mut sub_port = Port::new(20);
    let mut sub_sub_port = Port::new(30);

    sub_port.link(&top_port);
    sub_sub_port.link(&sub_port);

    top_port.value.store(400, Ordering::Relaxed);

    println!(
        "Value of sub_sub_port's source's source's source: {:?}",
        sub_sub_port.get_source_value()
    );
}
```

In general, atomic operations are known to be less efficient than *regular* operations, because of the care taken by the hardware in order to always expose the data in a consistent state for all the cores/CPUs.
On x86(_64), there is no difference for load/store, but on other architectures this could be the case (however for add, sub... there always are penalties).
The *relaxed* memory-order used here should not introduce memory-barriers, but other ordering could also be detrimental to performances.

Comment: This is cool and I upvoted, but OP did specify they'd prefer no std.

Comment: `core::Cell<i32>` would do the trick in non-concurrent environments.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks for noticing, I switched to `core`

Comment: @aedm Yes indeed, even better!

Comment: Wow, this is great @prog-fh and Thanks for thinking along everybody! In coming revisions I'd need to support generic data to flow through the ports but for now this will surely do!

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the difference between `AtomicI32` and `Cell<i32>` is that the atomic is `Sync` and the cell isn't, but the atomic will have higher performance overhead. The answer mentions both options but doesn't describe why you would prefer one over the other.

Comment: @cdhowie thanks for the remark, I tried to clarify.

Comment: Replacing `RefCell` with atomics is wrong. If `RefCell` works but you want to avoid the possible panic (or the performance overhead), use `Cell`. Atomics are replacement for `Mutex` or `RwLock`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In the original attempt, the intention was to replace `i32` with something else, that's why I thought about an atomic. But you are right, the main concern is mutability, not parallelism, which could be misleading on the intention. I switched the two propositions. Thanks for your help.